# How can I change default list style?

Tags: lists

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This generates list like:
• Item 1
• Item 2

Changing `article` to `mwrep` generates:
— Item 1
— Item 2

I want to use `mwrep` but with`article` list style.

Comment: Use `enumitem` package.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the `enumitem` package could be helpful here:

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]
 \item Item 1
 \item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

If you'd like to make the change globally, you can use the `\setlist` feature provided by `enumitem`

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[itemize]{label=\textbullet}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Item 1
 \item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! But how to edit other levels labels? `\documentclass{mwrep} \usepackage{enumitem} \setlist[itemize]{label=\textbullet} \begin{document} \begin{itemize} \item Item 1 \item Item 2 \begin{itemize} \item Item 1.i \item Item 1.ii \end{itemize} \end{itemize}
\end{document}`

Comment: Use, e.g., `\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textbullet}\setlist[itemize,2]{label=*}`. Note that your "answer" will likely be removed from public view soon -- asking a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) is the recommended way.

Answer (score 5):

Redefine `\labelitemi` locally (inside `itemize`) or globally in your document preamble:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \let\labelitemi\labelitemii
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 3
  \item Item 4
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Using `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\normalfont\bfseries\textendash}` would also work.

Defaults lists in LaTeX are managed as `\list`s, where each item is either numbered (in `enumerate`) or bulleted (in `itemize`). These item constructions are based on the following definitions:

```
% Labels for items in (nested) enumerate (uses counters)
\newcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.}% Default is arabic: 1.
\newcommand\labelenumii{(\theenumii)}% Default is alph: (a)
\newcommand\labelenumiii{\theenumiii.}% Default is roman: i.
\newcommand\labelenumiv{\theenumiv.}% Default is Alph: A.
% Labels for items in (nested) itemize (uses bullets/characters)
\newcommand\labelitemi{\textbullet}% bullet
\newcommand\labelitemii{\normalfont\bfseries \textendash}% --
\newcommand\labelitemiii{\textasteriskcentered}% *
\newcommand\labelitemiv{\textperiodcentered}% .
```

Note that there are four definitions for each list environment, corresponding to the (maximum) four levels of nested lists (this is for the standard document classes `article`, `book` and `report`). Redefining any of these modifies the list item representation at that level.

[`mwrep`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwcls) uses a similar definition for `enumerate`, but the following for `itemize`:

```
\newcommand\labelitemi{\textemdash}
\newcommand\labelitemii{\textemdash}
\newcommand\labelitemiii{\textemdash}
\newcommand\labelitemiv{\textemdash}
```

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) allows to extend this in a more general way and also to have more levels if needed.

Comment: +1 For giving the **default values of labels**.